# Any wordpress lightbox not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a wordpress theme from blank. But I have some problems. I installed Jetpack but Carousel is not working. If I select the twenty fifteen theme it is working. I also tried many lightbox plugins, but none of them work.

I think this problem is about `function.php`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This would probably be better asked on a WordPress forum or even a WP subreddit. SO is for specific programming related problems, not a general "what can I do" type question. If you were modifying something in wordpress and go stuck on how to do something complicated, that is what SO is for.

Comment: sorry but i am writing that problem to everywhere because my website have to work after 2 days. @JonathanKuhn

Answer (score 0):

There might be a javascript conflict on one of your plugins, and possibly, on your theme. To debug, first try to set your theme to twenty fifteen, after that deactivate all your plugins, except for the lightbox plugin that you're using. Check if the lightbox plugin is working. If it is, then start activating each plugin one a time. Everytime you activate a plugin, make sure to check the lightbox if it is working or not. If the lightbox stops working after a certain plugin is activated, then that could be a sign on conflict on the javascript.

Let me know if you we're able to do what I suggested. Also, it would be easier for others to help you if you can post a link to a site where you are trying to to install the lightbox.